# Laptop AC-to-DC converter considerations

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design

I’m currently working on a project that I plan to power using a laptop AC-to-DC converter.

-This is an example of what I am thinking of using.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B09H3BQ4W7/?coliid=I2OPFG6GBWNSRA&colid=3K9URHSGF62RC&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

This project is a sit/stand desk that uses 4 x (12v (1.5A under load)) dc motors and a Arduino mega for the logic and programming, with mosfets acting as switches for the motors.

Once the prototype is solid, I’ll  create a pcb using a barebones Arduino mega design.

As this is my first project using a laptop AC-to-DC converter as the supply, I’m wondering if there’s any considerations I have to make when designing my circuit/pcb for this type of supply.

Please point me to resources to read if applicable!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Laptop power supplies are usually 19-21V but your project needs 12V for the motors and 5V for the electronics. I’d suggest it would be more expedient to use a 12V power supply rated at 8-10Amps then use a buck supply for the 5V.

Comment: @Kartman And the 12-to-5V switching supplies are quite affordable as ready-made modules. So no need to design one from scratch either. There are even "switcher 7805" modules that are only slightly larger than an 7805, have same pinout, and use a switching buck converter for lower dissipation vs. the legacy 7805.

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear I was thinking of using an off-the-shelf converter. Thanks for input.